# Inheritance and getters and setters

Tags: actionscript-3

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class AbstractTarget extends Sprite 
    {
        private var __movement:IMovement;

        public function AbstractTarget()
        {
        }

        public function set movement(value:IMovement):void {
            __movement = value;
        }   

        public function get movement():IMovement {
            return __movement;
        }
    }
}
```

And then I have a class called "Target" that extends AbstractTarget...how do I access the __movement property? Do I have to write the getter and setter in my Target class also and override both functions/methods?

Answer (score 2):

You can't access a `private` variable from a subclass.

Try using `protected` instead of `private`. Protected variables are accessible from subclasses but not from outside code.